# How to retrieve compressed data from Oracle SQL database using Cx_Oracle Python?

Tags: python, compression, cx-oracle

Let's say I am doing a very complicated query and I want to retrieve the query results using Cx_Oracle from Python.

Right now I retrieve data using these lines:

```
result = cur_out.getvalue()
raw_data = result.fetchall()
```

When I see what is inside raw_data I get a very big list (million of observations) of tuples containing the query results.
These results are not compressed:

```
raw_data = [("Renult Kangoo 2008", "SPEED", 123),
            ("Renult Kangoo 2008", "SPEED", 125),
            ("Renult Kangoo 2008", "WEIGH", 1231),
            ("Renult Kangoo 2008", "SPEED", 112)..]
```

As you can see this data could be compressed very easy by creating a dict of correspondence

```
{"Renult Kangoo 2008":1,
 "SPEED":2,
 "WEIGHT"3}
```

And now instead of retrieving a million of observations with repeated characters I will have repetead numbers which will make data transfer smaller and also reduce the speed for retrieving all the data.

I want to achieve something like zip or rar compression. Is this implemented somehow in Cx_Oracle module?

If not, is there any workaround to solve this problem and make data transfer more efficient.

### Current Workaround

For now I am only retrieving car ids and variable ids, and their values in one query.

In other query I am retrieving car ids and car names, and in other query I retrieve variable ids and variable names.

Later, on the client I map the values which is less time consuming than sending millions of rows with repetitive data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do all sorts of mapping in the query to return different values, eg with the CASE or REPLACE clauses, or others. You could also do all sorts of mapping in a PL/SQL block.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I think you didn't understand me, correct me if I am wrong. What is causing my program to be slow is that I need some extra columns in my query that are always repetitve, like car name, car description, etc... That is the reason I would like compression in order to send data instead of sending always the same car name, just send an integer that represents the car name and later in the client map the correct values. Doing this manually in the PL/SQL block it's impossible (there are thousands of car names)

Comment: See my new edit, with the current workaround and tell me if you want if that is optimal or there is a better way.

Comment: Does Oracle provide any type of instant compression when is going to send the data? I am using most recent version of Cx_Oracle(python connection driver) and Instant Client

Comment: You misunderstand my answer: you can do a lot of what you want in SQL to avoid returning repetitive data; and you could do more in PL/SQL.  How you do this will depend on what you want. To get help with SQL and PL/SQL, post a question on https://asktom.oracle.com/   Regarding optimization, there are internal optimizations in the Oracle Client libraries.  When fetching rows in cx_Oracle (after you've tuned your SQL), you can set `arraysize` and `prefetchrows`, see https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance.